# R Survival: KM plots and statistics on two of three group values

Tags: r

brand new and could really use some help.

I'm working a cancer cohort in the 'survival' package. For each patient, there are values for survival (continuous, in days), censor (0/1) information, as well as about 30 genes with values of "High", "Low", or "Neither" for each gene.

When I've been working with just two category values, running the survival analysis to get the Kaplan-meier plots and log-rank test values is straightforward for me. My brain has been melting when trying to figure our the correct code to compare only two of three groups (i.e. "High" vs. "Low" for a particular gene). If I use `survdiff` for say `~data$geneA` it will only return the statistic comparing all three groups. I basically want to exclude the "Neither" group. Can someone help me with the code to do a `survdiff` function to specify the test on only two groups of a certain value when there are 3 (or more) values.

Similarly, (but less of an issue as I can set the "Neither" group to the transparent color), how to I generate the KM plots for only two groups?

Thanks much,

Edit: Some of the code I'm currently using

```
> B<-read.table("~/Desktop/breast.csv",header=T,sep=",")
> BR1=survfit(Surv(B$death,B$status)~B$GeneA)
> BR2=survfit(Surv(B$death,B$status)~B$GeneB)
```

And so on for genes to 30. Then for the statistics and KM curves:

```
> survdiff(Surv(B$death,B$status)~B$GeneB,rho=0)
> plot(BR1, xlim=c(0,3000), col=c("yellow3", "blue3", "transparent"))
```

I understand I can use 'subset' to define one value, such as

```
> BR3=survfit(Surv(B$death,B$status)~B$GeneB, subset=B$GeneB=="High")
```

But does can it work with two values? Doing what makes logical sense to me:

```
> BR4=survfit(Surv(B$death,B$status)~B$GeneB, subset=B$GeneB==c("Low", "High")
```

Doesn't work correctly, it splits up one of the groups into two?

Comment: Can you show some of the code you've already written?

Comment: Thanks much for offering to look at it. Edited the post to add the code. Best,

Comment: I cannot really replicate it as I don't have your data, but I think your issue lies in `B$GeneB==c("Low", "High")`. Boolean evaluations don't work that way in R. You could either use `%in%`, or use or (`|`).